# JtextPane doesn't show in JscrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane

I have a textpane which I want to add to a JscrollPane. But I can't see the textpane. What is wrong here?

```
        crimepanel.setBounds(new Rectangle(660, 250, 295, 35));
        scroll.setBounds(new Rectangle(655, 240, 305, 55));
        scroll.add(crimepanel);
        this.getContentPane().add(scroll, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(crimepanel, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Proper code is:

```
        scroll.getViewport().add(crimepanel, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(scroll, null);
```